# Save example in Postman

Tags: postman

I want to save examples in postman. I know how to do that. But request is saved with variable placeholders if request contains any.
For example if request is something like:

```
{
   id: {{someId}}
}}
```

In this example look the same way as request body - with variable place holder. Now I open console, open request body, copy and then paste in example's request. It is time consuming. Is there a way to force postman to save example with variable values?

Comment: why are are you saving example , what is the requirement ?

Comment: Just to have sample at hand. In my current case I'm doing integration with API and it is convenient feature to store examples of requests and responses, just awkward part is those variable placeholders

Comment: Variables are to show that , the data is dynamic or secret . There is no way to replace it separately instead you can export it as json and replace all variables using notepad plus or some other edditor

Comment: No so secret as full response is shown in console